# Why aren't the python bitwise operators working with what bin() returns

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitwise-operators

I've been doing some work with bitwise operators, which usually begins by using bin() to convert integers. I've been getting an error at each try.

```
foo = 5
binfoo = bin(foo)
bar = ~(binfoo)
```

The last line is where we get messed up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'str'
```

if bin() returns a string then what are these bitwise operators expecting?

Comment: The bitwise operators are expecting integers, try `~foo`. The `bin` function is for creating a binary *string representation*, for output.

Comment: Because `bin()` returns a string, not an integer number (bitwise operators work on *integers*, not strings).

Comment: Under the hood integers *are* bit patterns -- which the bitwise operators work on directly. They don't work on the string representation of those bit patterns. Why do you think that bitwise operators "usually begin" with using `bin()`? In fact -- they *never* begin that way. Still -- this is a useful question in the sense that it is a fairly natural question for someone new to programming to ask. I don't think that it deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `~` unary bitwise operator require *integer input*. From the [*Unary arithmetic and bitwise operations* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) of the *Expressions* chapter of the Python reference documentation:

> The unary `~` (invert) operator yields the bitwise inversion of its **integer argument**. The bitwise inversion of `x` is defined as `-(x+1)`. It only applies to integral numbers.

Bold emphasis mine.

Applying `~` to `5` works just fine:

```
>>> ~5
-6
```

The `bin()` function only returns a *string* object with the binary representation of a number. Think of this as a debugging tool, something that can quickly show you what bits are set and not set for an integer number. To actually manipulate bits, you still need an integer.